# run app/console via SSH

Tags: symfony, ssh

I'm hosting at "godaddy". I'm trying now run a console `php app/console donctrine:schema:create` via ssh.

I got error: `Could not open input file: app/console` or `-bash: app/console: No such file or directory`.

How can I fix that?

Comment: What is your current directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the absolute path of `console` or go to current path of project before to execte command.